# API Integration With Facebook - Testing

Tags: facebook, integration-testing, web-api-testing

I am working on API Integration Tests. In particular, I am trying to test the user's ability to login to our application with Facebook. Prior to signing in with our API, the user must sign in with Facebook on the front end of the application via the steps listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login). Since the tests going to be backend integration tests, I would like to handle the entire login in flow solely by leveraging Facebook's API. I can't seem to find any docs that illustrate a methodology to do what the [these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login) docs allow the front end to do. Does anyone have en experience with Facebook's API, and know how to simulate the login flow without actually using the login dialogue window?

**Sign In Steps**

1. Log in to Facebook
2. Log in to our API with Facebook returned authentication credentials and redirect uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their test user capability should help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

It'll allow you to create & sign into a test account, then destroy it afterwards. It won't be limited to normal login & visibility restrictions either.

Comment: ha, you know i forgot I had this question open still. I did resolve it and ended up doing so with the test-users. I am going to accept your answer in hopes it helps someone in the future. Cheers!